# Can I write to cells from within a VBA function (if that function is the data source of another cell)?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a workbook in Excel 2019, which contains only one worksheet. The workbook is opened from a trusted location, and I have enabled macro execution.

I created a **VBA module** with the following code (nothing else):

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function Foo(ByVal Bar As Integer) As String
  Foo = "John"
End Function
```

In the worksheet, all cells are empty, except `A1`, which contains the following formula:

```
=Foo(1)
```

If I let the worksheet calculate (CTRL-ALT-F9), the text `John` appears in `A1`.

Now I enter the text `Mary` into cell `B1` and change the VBA function as follows:

```vb
Public Function Foo(ByVal Bar As Integer) As String
  Dim s As Worksheet
  Set s = ActiveWorksheet
  MsgBox s.Range("B1").Value
  Foo = "John"
End Function
```

When I let the worksheet recalculate, a message box appears which contains the text `Mary`, and the text `John` again appears in `A1`.

Now I change the VBA function as follows:

```vb
Public Function Foo(ByVal Bar As Integer) As String
  Dim s As Worksheet
  Set s = ActiveWorksheet
  s.Range("C1").Value = "April"
  Foo = "John"
End Function
```

I expect the text `April` to appear in `C1` and again the text `John` to appear in `A1` when I recalculate the sheet.

However, `#VALUE` appears in `A1`, and nothing appears in `A3`. If I debug the function during recalculation, it doesn't execute the line which begins with `s.Range ...`, but there is no error message, neither at compile time nor at runtime. It just leaves the function silently before executing the last line.

Afterwards, there a lightbulb icon besides `A1`. When I hover the mouse over it, it says:

> A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type.

If I let that function run from within the "Immediate" window in the VBA editor (by typing `? Foo(1)` there), it works as expected, i.e. the text `April` appears in `C1`.

I checked that `A3` is not protected and is formatted as text.

Does Excel prevent writing to cells from within functions which act as data source for other cells?

Comment: This is a limitation of UDFs used in cells - nothing to do with your version of Excel. There are ways to work around it, but it's generally a bad idea for a function in one cell to write to other cells.

Comment: At least, it's not that I have been to silly. Too sad that this is not supported. We're having a nasty problem here with Excel calculating cells and formulas in the wrong order under certain circumstances, and could have solved that problem easily if we could do this. Now we'll try to solve the problem with the help of a bunch of event procedures. Thank you very much, +1, and if you put your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.